# using BootStrap template. trying to replace an SVG icon but cannot find location

Tags: svg, replace, icons, dreamweaver

all. Im very new to web design and have been experimenting with a bootstrap template and  dream weaver.

There are some icons that I would like to change but i cannot figure out how to change them and any help would be very greatly appreciated.

I cannot find where these icons are saved in the template folder.

I hope the photo provides some kind of clarity to anyone gracious enough to give me some pointers. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o2T5.png)

I've tried clicked the svg file and seeing if it was possible to replace with an path icon that I've created in photoshop.